Fetching data using useEffect hook
I have a component that fetches data from an API (nodeJS server). All my fetch code is an useEffect hook. But on running the code the useEffect code does not run as i am unable to see my console.log statements and my state is not set.
Is there anything wrong with my code, as I have referred articles online and tried many approaches
How do I set my state variable once the useEffect is run and any help is understanding useEffect would be helpful.

export default function SummaryContainer() {
  /* const { transactions, setTransactions } = useTransactionContext(); */
  let apiData = null;
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/getExpenseSummary";

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Fetched Data");
        setSummary(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  /* const expenseSummary = calculateExpenses(transactions) ?? null; */

  return (
    <div>
      {summary.map((expense, idx) => {
        const formattedString =
          expense[0].slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + expense[0].slice(1);
        return (
          <Summary
            key={idx}
            title={formattedString}
            value={expense[1]}
            desc={"Total " + formattedString}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}




why do you have a apiData variable ?

@underscore That was for one of the approaches I used, the had said store response in another variable and then set the state

Your code is correct. There might be issue with expense[0] that is used in the formatted string. Since we do not have what the response is from the backend, I cannot say if the expense field is an array or not. Here I have added my changes, with the condition that the expense field might be a key-value pair.
You can also make the value capital using the css property capitalize.
CodeSandbox
Text Transform - Capitalize
Do note that I have made the first 3 letters capital, since the response already has the first letter in capital.
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Fetched Data");
        setSummary(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  /* const expenseSummary = calculateExpenses(transactions) ?? null; */

  return (
    <div>
      {summary.length > 0 ? (
        summary.map((expense, idx) => {
          const formattedString =
            expense.name.slice(0, 3).toUpperCase() + expense.name.slice(1);
          return (
            <>
              <b>{formattedString}</b> <br />{" "}
            </>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <p>Fetching data...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


Thank you for the help, error has been resolved
